# Is it possible to emit an event using a standard HTML button?

Tags: javascript, aframe

Maybe this is a really stupid question, but I can't figure it out.

Basically all I want to do is emit a single event when the screen is touched (using a physical button on the model of google cardboard that we are ordering). Couldn't work out how to have a 'whole screen touch' so I made a button element outside the a-scene. This is positioned absolutely at the point where the button hits the screen, and console logs when clicked (via mouse) - so I know that the button works. However, trying to emit an event or setAttribute does nothing.

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is there just some other approach entirely that is better suited?

Here's the code:

```
<body>
    <button id="nav-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Menu</button>
    <a-scene id="scene">
```

and:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('nav', {
    schema: {},

    init: function () {
        var navBtn = document.querySelector('#nav-btn');
        var btnEls = document.querySelectorAll('.link');

        navBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            console.log('clicked');

            for (var i = 0; i < btnEls.length; i++) {
                console.log(btnEls[i]);
                btnEls[i].emit('menuFade');
            }
        }); 
    },
});
```

This works when using an a-entity as a button by the way, but I also couldn't find out how to make that work as a physical button!?

Thanks for any help or advice!

Comment: @AaronTomlinson thanks! That is handy to know (and so simple.. omg, can't believe I had to ask) - but doesn't help the emit unfortunately :/

Comment: For `getAttribute()` to work shouldn't you be targeting that element. I'm sure your console log will return `undefined` if anything... seems to be missing `btnEls[i].` in front of it. That's the first thing to stand out to me for your source code, also `btnEls[i].emit('menuFade');` since `btnEls` is nothing but a node list?

Comment: @NewToJS oops, sorry, I should have read through what I posted a bit better. My code is a bit of a mess of different attempts to get this to work... That 'getAttribute' was a leftover from something else I was trying, and I had tried it with [i] before hand but same deal :/

Comment: When working with javascript many things are stored in variables and if you are unsure of what that variable will contain use `console.log(YouVar);` and check the console. This will help you so much, same with running if conditions, can't work out why it always returns the same thing? check the condition with `console.log();` it will help you debug and understand how things like `document.querySelectorAll();` work and the return of it so you know how to deal with that result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you care about figuring out when the physical button is pressed on a Google Cardboard, then you don't even need a button element. Attach a "click" or "touchstart" handler to the `window` and you should be good:

```
window.addEventListener('touchstart', function(evt) {
  console.log('there we go')
})
```

Note that `emit` isn't a vanilla JS way of emitting events but an A-Frame specific function, which is why it won't work from a button.

You can use `dispatchEvent` and `CustomEvent` for that instead:

```
window.addEventListener('touchstart', function(evt) {
  console.log('there we go')
  window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('menuFade'))
})
```

You may need to change the object that emits the event to something inside the `a-scene` but it should work.

Comment: Thank you so SO much! That is exactly what I was after - truly appreciate it mate.